# How to get the fonts directory path in different OS?

Tags: python, fonts, cross-platform

I'm developing a module for generate CAPTCHA. This module needs a font file, but the fonts directory path are different in different operating system. Is there a universal way to get the fonts directory path that can be used in different OS?

Comment: I think your code will have to test which OS its running on and use that OSs specific font path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any such library, atmost wxPython have a [wxStandarPaths](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxstandardpaths.html) which can give OS specific paths, may be you can use that to get fonts folder.

But I think even with that you will have to do tweaks per OS, so easiest way is to just create you own function `get_font_folder` and keep on adding OS to font folder mapping as you test or find bugs :)

Answer (score 1):

Do it with [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo_pango/). You don't even need to know the system font path. You just do

```
font_map = pangocairo.cairo_font_map_get_default()
families = font_map.list_families()
```

and you have a list of all the font families.

You can also get a font by its name like

```
font = pango.FontDescription("Utopia 22")
```

If you're on a Unix ecosystem then it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is exactly what you want, but this helped me:

```py
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

font_path = fm.findfont('Arial')
print(font_path)
```